# Why is Carrie Fisher's car damaged in The Blues Brothers?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blues-brothers

In *The Blues Brothers*, we see Carrie Fisher's character seeking revenge on Jake Blues, driving a pink 1977 Pontiac Grand Prix. It seems to have some damage to the front, especially the tip of the bonnet.

[image: A screen shot from The Blues Brothers, featuring Carrie Fisher's character's car, a pink 1977 Pontiac Grand Prix, with damage to its bonnet highlighted by a hand-drawn red circle. It's parked underneath a railway overpass, across a hotel. It's night-time and the street is wet.]

How did it get damaged? Was that part of a dropped plotline? Is there another explanation?

Comment: *Old cars* have damage. It might just be the car they elected to use was already damaged.

Comment: @Paulie_D _The Blues Brothers_ was filmed in 1978–1980. That model Pontiac Grand Prix was in production from 1970–1977, if I'm correct. So it wasn't necessarily _that_ old — 10 years at the most.

Comment: @SQB - in American English what you call a bonnet is called a hood, which could be useful to know if you ever need damage repaired in the USA..

Comment: @Paulie_D looking into it a bit more, this seems to be the 1977 version of the fourth generation model, as can be seen by the square headlights with parking lights between them.

Comment: @SQB - for context, though, having a car last more than 100K miles without serious issues was not nearly as common back then. The or was the quality of weather proofing the metal and the percentage of non-metal in the body was also different, so "10 years, at most" would represent a pretty old car, back then.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yeah, but it seems to be the '77 model, so it's more like 3 years.

Comment: @SQB - I'll take your word for it. I can replace my own brakes and wheel hubs, but I don't know cars that well.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet neither do I, I just looked on Wikipedia and found that that year's model had very distinctive headlights.

Answer (score 4):

There's no in-universe explanation.  It was just the sort of car you'd expect a jilted ex-fiance of a bluesman who has a working knowledge of rocket launchers and AR-15's to drive.  You wouldn't think she'd have a BMW 5-series, would you?  Of course it's been in an accident (or two...), visibly needs some bodywork and is big enough to comfortably store a flamethrower.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support that?

Comment: Watch her use the AR-15, she definitely doesn't have a working knowledge of it. bizarrely she seems fine with explosives, a flamethrower and the rocket launcher but not the AR, she doesn't even know how to aim it.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know or care why or how it happens because that's not important. I think it's simply to demonstrate that she's not well-to-do. There are lots of movies where people are seen diving "beater" vehicles. This is no different. They probably thought that kind of damage was, visually, more humorous.

The damage doesn't prevent the car from working, so while others might find driving around in a dinged-up vehicle to be embarrassing, you see a lot more of that in lower income areas because economic reality will trump social and cosmetic concerns that might win out with people with greater means and insurance coverage.